# How do you ignore records with a date of 12/31/2999 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, date

I'm working with records in a database, many of which have the date 12/31/2999 12:00:00 AM. How can I ignore those dates? The field is a datetime field. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why these aren't NULL? I presume you are using it as a sentinel value for N/A?

Comment: please provide the **data type** for that column (together with your previous question), you can not compare if the column is in varchar/text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add something to your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE `date` <> '2999-12-31 0:00:00'
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. It still shows me dates with the value 12/31/2999 12:00:00 AM. I tried date <> '12/31/2999 12:00:00 AM' and date <> '2999-12-31 0:00:00'

Comment: @Louise, try this predicate: WHERE DATE(`date`) <> STR_TO_DATE('12/31/2999','%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

Its mutch simpler to TypeCast the field in your Case:

```
WHERE DATE(tbl.field) <> 'Y-m-d'
```

eg.:

```
WHERE DATE(`date`) <> '2999-12-31'
```